# how to extract values from list with different amounts of brackets?

Tags: python, list

I have to extract values from a list, but it only works when I have a list with a double bracket (bbox=[[]]), when it has a single bracket (bbox=[]) it gives me this error: cannot unpack non-iterable int object.

```
#bboxes = [[396, 386, 531, 586], [449, 387, 536, 494]]
bboxes = [396, 386, 531, 586]
instp = []
if not instp:
  instp = bboxes
for i in bboxes:
  x1,y1,x2,y2 = i
  bbox = [x1,y1,x2,y2]
  print("bbox",bbox)
```

How can I make my code work in both cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract from single list, you don't need the for-loop. Just write

```
x1,y1,x2,y2 = bboxes
```

To make your code work in both cases, you could for example check if the type of the first element in the list is `list` or `int` and use the for-loop or simple unpack solution bases on that:

```
if isinstance(bboxes[0], int):
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = bboxes
else:
    # for-loop etc.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm new to python and I didn't know how to do it